# Moving files with the same names in one folder without overwritten?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenotfounderror

I made a script for organize files, and it working well.
my issue happen when it overwritten files with the same name.
so i made a variable [i] inside while loop to added if the moving file exists.

```
from genericpath import isdir
import os
import shutil

# Set File Path ------------------------------
print(os.getcwd())
path = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Set Dict for files Extensions. -------------
IMAGES = (".jpeg", ".jpg", ".tiff", ".gif", ".bmp", ".png")

VIDEOS = (
    ".avi", ".flv", ".wmv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".webm", 
        ".vob", ".mng", ".qt", ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".3gp"
    )

ARCHIVES = (
    ".a", ".ar", ".cpio", ".iso", ".tar", ".gz", ".rz", 
        ".7z", ".dmg", ".rar", ".xar", ".zip"
    )

AUDIO = (
    ".aac", ".aa", ".aac", ".dvf", ".m4a", ".m4b", ".m4p",       
        ".mp3", ".msv", "ogg", "oga", ".raw", ".vox", ".wav", 
           ".wma"
    )

DOCUMENTS = (
    ".pdf", ".oxps", ".epub", ".pages", ".docx", ".doc", ".fdf",
         ".ods", ".odt", ".pwi", ".xsn", ".xps", ".dotx",     
             ".docm", ".dox", ".rvg", ".rtf", ".rtfd", ".wpd",
                ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ppt", "pptx", ".csv", ".txt", 
                   ".in", ".out"
    )

 PROGRAMS = (".exe", ".msi")

# Set list of Files in current dir. ----------
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

# Moving Files. ------------------------------
print('\n>>>> Start Organizing Files. <<<<\n')
for file in dir_list:
    i = 1
    if file == 'Folder-Organizer.py':
        pass

# Move [IMGs]. --------------------------------
    if file.endswith(IMAGES):
        while os.path.isfile(f'{path}\IMGs\{file}'):
            i += 1
            duplicated = os.path.splitext(file)
            file = f'{duplicated[0]}{i}{duplicated[1]}'
        
        shutil.copy(file, 'IMGs')
        os.remove(file)
```

But it raising This Error each time the loop running.

```
in copyfile with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:    
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Comment: It seems like the purpose of the `while` loop is to assemble a filename that _does not_ exist.  So of course you will get an error when you try to move that filename...

Comment: It's hard to assist you when your code snippet is incomplete. please add the part where `file` variable is defined

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite the target you should check first for its existence. Also, instead of shutil.copy and os.remove you could just shutil.move

Comment: I am added the most of the code now, so sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnGordon it seems this is the issue, how can i solve it ?

Comment: Before calling *shutil.copy()* write *print(file)*. That will help you

Answer (score 1):

For every one have the same issue, I found the solution.
The shutil.move raise error (file not found) bcz the while loop change file name inside python environment but not in the directory.
So you need to use os.rename module to change the file to the new name first then the shutil.move do the rest.